# python 3.4, timer count down not working

Tags: python, timer, countdown

I want to create a clock that count down in hours min and seconds, but for some reason is not working, can somebody help me

```
def countdown():
  times = 1
  th = 1
  tm = 0
  ts = 0
  while times != 0:
    if (ts>0 or tm>0 or th>0):
      print ('it run for ' + str(th) + ' Hours ' + str(tm) + ' Minutes ' + str(ts) + ' Seconds ')
      time.sleep(1)
      ts = ts - 1
      if (ts==0 and (tm>0 or th>0)):
        ts = 59
        tm = tm - 1
        if(ts==0 or tm==0 and th>0):
          ts = 59
          tm = 59
          th = th - 1
          if (ts==0 and tm==0 and th==0):          
            times = 0
  else:
    print ('stopped')
    ts = 0
    tm = 0
    th = 0

countdown()
```

thanks

Comment: What is it doing that is unexpected?

Comment: your `ts = 0` before gets into the `while loop`,  `ts = ts - 1` makes `ts!=0` so it will not get into the next `if`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much simpler method is would be to use  [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) and `time.sleep`

In a function, where you can pass in days,hours,mins and seconds to countdown from:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

def countdown(d=0, h=0, m=0, s=0):
    counter = timedelta(days=d, hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)
    while counter:
        time.sleep(1)
        counter -= timedelta(seconds=1)
        print("Time remaining: {}".format(counter))
```

An example counting down 5 seconds:

```
In [2]: countdown(s=5)
Time remaining: 0:00:04
Time remaining: 0:00:03
Time remaining: 0:00:02
Time remaining: 0:00:01
Time remaining: 0:00:00
```

Two hours:

```
In [3]: countdown(h=2)
Time remaining: 1:59:59
Time remaining: 1:59:58
Time remaining: 1:59:57
Time remaining: 1:59:56
Time remaining: 1:59:55
Time remaining: 1:59:54
```

Comment: question If I want to use this function timedelta to add seconds instead of subtracting them, which part of the code do I change?

Comment: `counter += timedelta(seconds=1)`

Comment: but you will have to make sure you set a stop condition in the while loop.

Comment: I want to have 2 timers, one going down, and at the same time one going up, so can I put in the while counter, counter1 -= timedelta(seconds=1) and counter2 += timedelta(seconds=1) and print("Time remaining: {}".format(counter1) + " Time:{}".format(counter2) )????

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
import time

def countdown():
  count = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
  while count:
    print ('it run for ' + str(count))
    time.sleep(1)
    count -= datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

  print ('stopped')

countdown()
```